# Why is my Euler discretization error increasing with number of steps?

Tags: programming, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to see how the Euler discretization error behaves with respect to the number of steps. To do this I'm simulating a [geometric brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Brownian_motion) and comparing it with it's 'exact' solution. However when using the root mean squared error as a measure of the error it is increasing with the number of steps, which is very weird! So now I'm confused if I made a coding error or I'm just missing something. Help would be appreciated!

Here is my matlab code, I hope it is self explanatory. (The problem is that the elements of meanvec are increasing while it is expected they decrease)

```
X0=100;
mu=0.04;
sigma=0.2;
T=10;
M=10^5;
meanvec=zeros(6,1);

for i=1:6
    N=2^i;
    dt=T/N;

    t=0;
    X=X0;
    for k=1:N
        dW = sqrt(dt)*randn(M,1);
        dX = mu*X*dt + sigma*X.*dW;
        X  = X + dX;
        t  = t + dt;
    end
    Y=100.*exp((mu-sigma^2/2)*T+sigma.*sqrt(T).*randn(M,1));

    meanvec(i)=sqrt(mean((X-Y).^2))/mean(Y);
end
```

Comment: surely it should increase with the step size?

Comment: Sorry, ofcourse I mean increasing number of steps (so decreasing stepsize), if N increases one expects the euler method to become more accurate, so X to be closer to Y.

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it a bit more I realized what the problem is. Y is generated with different increments than X, while I should use the same. I fixed this and know it is decreasing.

Comment: You should include the correct version of the code in your answer an mark it as accepted.